# Why does my code get a null reference when allocating a very large array on Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I have this (not at all useful, just to illustrate the problem) code:

```
var arr = new long[1000 * 1000 * 1000];
Console.WriteLine("Array allocated");
if (arr == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("arr is null");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("arr is not null");
}
Console.WriteLine("Array length is " + arr.Length.ToString());
```

When this code runs on Windows under .NET 4.5 I get `System.OutOfMemoryException` on the first line because arrays larger than 2 gigabytes are not currently supported.

When I run this on Ubuntu Server 14 under Mono 4.6.2.16 I get the following output:

```
Array allocated
arr is null
Unhandled Exception:
   System.NullReferenceException
```

So it looks like `new[]` silently returns a null reference and no exception is thrown at that point.

What's that? Is this a bug in Mono or is it something useful?

Comment: I would say that is a bug... FYI: With v4.8 I get `System.OutOfMemoryException` using `mono32` and using `mono64` it allocates the array as expected.

Comment: Is that v4.8 of Mono?

Comment: yes, latest preview release : mono-4.8.0.472